# Attempt to add bootstrap.min.js file results in "Unable to resolve the source file" error

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, custom

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I added the *latest version of Bootstrap 3* to my theme (v3.3.7). The path to `bootstrap.min.js` is:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/bootstrap.min.js

In

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

I have added `<script src="../Magento_Theme/web/js/bootstrap.min.js" />`.

Yet I get the error: `Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/bootstrap.min.js'` in the console.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

Put js in following location :

```
frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/web/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

You correct your code by adding this:

```
<script src="Magento_Theme::js/bootstrap.min.js" />
```